# The argument type 'Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'

Tags: flutter

I have a function which fetch a stream and do querysnapshot in cloud firestore to fetch some data and then return it.

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getSearchedUser() async {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> users = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: searchUserTextController.text)
        .snapshots();
    return users;
  }
```

and I am trying to function as stream in my stream builder but I am getting an error

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: getSearchedUser(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return const Text("Error Occured");
                      }
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Text("Loading Data");
                      }
                      final data = snapshot.requireData;
                      return ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: data.size,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Text("${data.docs[index]["email"]}");
                          });
                    },
                  ),
```

Error is: -

```
The argument type 'Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need 'Future' keyword because Stream already async structure.

So, you can ty below code;

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getSearchedUser() async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: searchUserTextController.text)
        .snapshots();
  }
```